# Should I upgrade to Grub2?

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, grub

Right now I'm running Ubuntu 10.10 with Grub Legacy. Everything runs fine and I've heard the old adage "if it ain't broke, don't fix it," but I'm truly interested if Grub2 brings anything new the table that would be useful. Does it boot faster? Have a nicer boot menu? Should I risk breaking something by upgrading to Grub2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been running Grub2 for quite some time already on my Debian systems; every software has bugs of course, but I would expect Grub2 to be reliable enough by now. OTOH here aren't many compelling reasons to upgrade (unless you like things like grub-set-default of course), and some people like grub-legacy better because it's simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly, but if we then look by how much it boots faster or how more beautiful the menu is it might not be worth it. It's your personal choice if you care about how shiny it is, or sparing out just a small bit of seconds...

Answer (score 0):

I don't like Grub2, I think it completely took the control out of the hands of those users who have limited tech knowledge.

However, I realized that struggling to keep GrubLegacy is like swimming against the drift.

It's not maintained. You will get less and less help in your endeavor.

Now back to your case:
It's working well, leave it as it is.
When it doesn't, upgrade it.

Comment: "took the control out of the hands of those users who have limited tech knowledge" - I agree, these types of users should have unlimited control over the boot process.

Comment: Some of them don't understand all the script puzzle of Grub2 but handle quite well their boot process with Grub1 without any problem whatsoever. Grub2 turned avanced scripting a requisite for boot managing.

Comment: I suppose. Editing the /etc/default/grub.cfg was fairly straight forward. But I agree, it becomes much more complicated when you want to get into the advanced stuff.